# Distance matrix in kilometres from latitude and longitude data in matlab

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I have a list of 2410 locations given by their latitude and longitude. I want to create a distance matrix in kilometres. I know how to do this in degrees but how do I do this in kilometres? I have the mapping toolbox, using 2016b. Thanks!

For example, my distance matrix in degrees looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ask your self what you mean by distance.

Do you want the euclidean distance between the points? Imagine you could tunnel through the earth from one point to the other, this is the euclidean distance between the points. To calculate this distance you need to first convert each of the lat long points to ecef points. You can do this conversion with this code (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7942-covert-lat--lon--alt-to-ecef-cartesian). After you've converted each point to an ecef point you can now calculate the euclidean norm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) between each possible pair of points.

Or do you want to calculate the distance a traveler would traverse if they were to walk along the surface of the earth. From the looks of it, this is a much more difficult problem requiring an iterative solver. Fortunately someone has already done the work of implementing an algorithm to do this for you (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5379-geodetic-distance-on-wgs84-earth-ellipsoid). Note if you read the comments of this function it appears as if mathworks has already implemented a different algorithm to perform the same calculation in the mapping toolbox. To calculate the matrix you simply need to iterate over each possible pairing of lat long points and plug them into the vdist function.

Following should calculate the distance matrix for you using the vdist function above. Note I have not tested this code so you may to to correct errors.

```
points % assuming this is a matrix of your points [2 x N] formatted as follows
%   [ lat1 , lat2, ... ]
%   [ lon1 , lat2, ... ]

dist = zeros(N,N); % the resulting distance matrix

for(idx1 = 1:N)
    for(idx2 = 1:N)
      dist(idx1,idx2) = vdist(points(1,idx1),points(2,idx1),points(1,idx2)points(2,idx2) );
    end
end
```

Note because the earth surface is manifold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) the results will be similar if the points are close to each other. If speed is  important to you and the points are closely grouped, you may want to use the first method to calculate your distance matrix. How close together the points should be to make use of this approximation will depend on how accurate you need the results to be.

Comment: thanks - I want the second option. I'm not really sure how to code this from a list of latitude and longitude points. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I changed one line slightly: `points = [lat lon];
N = 2410; %number of places

dist = zeros(N,N); % the resulting distance matrix

for idx1 = 1:N
    for idx2 = 1:N
      dist(idx1,idx2) = vdist(points(1,idx1),points(1,idx2),points(2,idx1),points(2,idx2) );
    end
end` but I'm getting the error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Comment: What is the matrix where your index is exceeded? Is it the  points matrix? My guess is that it is. What is the output of size(points) ?

Comment: `ans = 2410   2`. In the meantime though, the function `deg2km` seems to work (I'm not sure if it's as good)